# Why is a discrete algebraic subset of $K^n$ finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, field-theory, zariski-topology

Let $K$ be any field. If $A$ is the zero set of a polynomial $P\in K[X]$, then $A$ is finite. This follows from the fact that $K[X]$ is Euclidian, using commutativity of $K$.

Now let $A\subset K^n$ be an algebraic subset, *i.e.* the zero set of finitely many polynomials $P_1,\dots,P_q\in K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.

> If all points of $A$ are isolated for the Zariski topology on $K^n$, *i.e.* $A$ is **discrete**, why is $A$ necessarilly finite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is quasi-compact, since it is a closed subset of the quasi-compact set $K^n$. Any quasi-compact discrete set is finite, this is a very easy exercise in basic topology.

Comment: Thanks. I get why compactness and discrete implies finite. So the reaon seems to come from the fact that the ring $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @Drike I don't think so. $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is always quasi-compact, regardless of whether $R$ is Noetherian or not.

Comment: @AymanHourieh. But is $Spec R$ being quasi-compact always equivalent to $R^n$ being quasi-compact ? Even if there is no Hillbertnullstellensatz type connexion ?

Comment: Indeed, if we want to show that $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^n$ is compact, we need the noetherian property. If we want to show that $\mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^n$ is compact, we do not. I have never thought about this before.